# Passing object class for generics

Tags: java, generics, java-7

say I have a method which accepts a class:

```
private static <T> void otherFunction(Class<T> clazz) {
}
```

and two methods that pass a class to it:

```
private <T> void someFunc1(T someThing, Class<T> clazz) {
  otherFunction(clazz);
}

private <T> void someFunc2(T someThing) {
  otherFunction(someThing.getClass());
}
```

The first, explicit method of passing works fine, while the second throws a compile time exception. How are the two implementations different? And is it possible to build this kind of functionality, without explicitly passing the generics class in the first place?

Comment: I'm not getting any compiler errors, other than a missing return statement for the first function. This seems like one of those cases where making a [mcve] would solve the problem.

Comment: Could you please fix the question with valid java code? Java allows only one return statement.

Comment: If I take your statement “throws a compile time exception” literally, you have found a compiler bug. A compiler should not throw exceptions. In that case you should be specify the exact version of the compiler. Otherwise, if you only wanted to say that there is a compilation error message, you should include that message in your question.